# $lookup to Join within Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `Clients`,`Forms`

`Clients` schema has following record

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0bd79adcbf901ee404d8c0"),
"Name" : "Danielle",
"Email" : "Janet@test.com",
"Projects" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b1e6f3410ef671cf82404be"),
        "Name" : "test",
        "Description" : "ttet",
        "Forms" : [
            ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
            ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
            ObjectId("5afc23f3382646009c5210ab"),
        ],
        "IsActive" : true
    }, {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ffc11c70c513bc9dbfb1"),
        "Name" : "apadei ief",
        "Description" : "ttasdadet",
        "Forms" : [
            ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
            ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28")
        ],
        "IsActive" : true
    }, {
        // array of projects
    }
],
"IsDeleted" : false,
```

}

`Forms` schema has following record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
    "Name" : "Employee Information",
    "Description" : "",
    "IsActive" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
    "Name" : "test form",
    "Description" : "",
    "IsActive" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afc23f3382646009c5210ab"),
    "Name" : "Android test",
    "Description" : "",
    "IsActive" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c8"),
    "Name" : "feedback form",
    "Description" : "",
    "IsActive" : true
}
```

I want output be like as below

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0bd79adcbf901ee404d8c0"),
    "Name" : "Danielle",
    "Email" : "Janet@test.com",
    "Projects" : [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b1e6f3410ef671cf82404be"),
            "Name" : "test",
            "Description" : "ttet",
            "Forms" : [{
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
                    "Name" : "Employee Information",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "IsActive" : true
                }, {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
                    "Name" : "test form",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "IsActive" : true
                }, {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5afc23f3382646009c5210ab"),
                    "Name" : "Android test",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "IsActive" : true
                }
            ],
            "IsActive" : true
        }, {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ffc11c70c513bc9dbfb1"),
            "Name" : "apadei ief",
            "Description" : "ttasdadet",
            "Forms" : [{
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
                    "Name" : "Employee Information",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "IsActive" : true
                }, {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
                    "Name" : "test form",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "IsActive" : true
                }
            ],
            "IsActive" : true
        }, {
            // array of projects
        }
    ],
    "IsDeleted" : false
}
```

As per output i want forms should be come from `Forms` collections.

For this I am doing aggregation as below,

```
db.Clients.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                _id : ObjectId("5a8528ed0290f7eca89e9a5f"),
                IsDeleted : false
            }
        }, {
            $addFields : {
                "Forms" : {
                    $map : {
                        input : {
                            $map : {
                                input : "$Projects",
                                in : {
                                    $arrayElemAt : [{
                                            $objectToArray : "$$this"
                                        }, 1]
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        in : "$$this.v"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : "Forms",
                localField : "Projects.Forms",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as : "Forms"
            }
        }, {
            $addFields : {
                "Forms" : {
                    $arrayElemAt : ["$Forms", 0]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

but it give me wrong output,it returns only one `Form` from one project.I want each `Forms` from each `Projects`.

Your answer is working fine for me, but what if i want to make filter within the $map for

```
$and: [{
   $eq: ["$Projects.IsActive", true]
}, {
   $eq: ["$Projects.IsDeleted", false]
}]
```

Comment: Sorry but 2 hours ago there was no code on the question at all and just some data asking "how do I join". I see you added code shortly afterwards, so it would have been a good idea to make the comment when you made the changes. Anyhow you have a way to do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Being that you appear to have MongoDB 3.6 available to you by some of the features you are attempting to use, then you may as well use the ones that really matter. Namely the "sub-pipeline" form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) that allows the declaration of an expression to match:

```
db.Clients.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "_id": ObjectId("5a8528ed0290f7eca89e9a5f"), "IsDeleted": false } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Forms",
    "let": {
      "join": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$Projects.Forms",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
      }
    },
    "as": "join",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { 
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$join" ] }
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "Projects": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Projects",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            { 
              "Forms": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this.Forms",
                  "in": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$join",
                      { "$indexOfArray": [ "$join._id", "$$this" ] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "join": "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

Basically you do the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) after using the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) in order to "flatten" your nested array detail into a singular list of matching `"Forms"` `ObjectId` values. These can be compared to the foreign collection to return the correct related items.

Provided that there are no "missing" items in the foreign collection and all referenced items match, then it's really just a matter of processing the arrays using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and swapping out the "joined" content from the `"Forms"` for the existing `ObjectId` values. Again since you're using MongoDB 3.6 you can use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) in order to make the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operations a bit more flexible without actually naming all properties explicitly.

The matching here is done using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to find the "match" and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in order to extract that value and swap it out during the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/).

Even without MongoDB 3.6, you can still do pretty much the same thing:

```
db.Clients.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "_id": ObjectId("5a8528ed0290f7eca89e9a5f"), "IsDeleted": false } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "join": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$Projects.Forms",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Forms",
    "localField": "join",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "join"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Name": 1,
    "Email": 1,
    "Projects": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Projects",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$this._id",
          "Name": "$$this.Name",
          "Description": "$$this.Description",
          "Forms": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$this.Forms",
              "in": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$join",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [ "$join._id", "$$this" ] }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "IsActive": "$$this.IsActive"
        }
      }
    },
    "IsDeleted": 1
  }}
])
```

Just a little longer since you need to add the "flattened" array content before the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and then also don't have the other features to fully enable the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) on remapping the arrays so we use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead.

Both ways return the same thing:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0bd79adcbf901ee404d8c0"),
        "Name" : "Danielle",
        "Email" : "Janet@test.com",
        "Projects" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b1e6f3410ef671cf82404be"),
                        "Name" : "test",
                        "Description" : "ttet",
                        "Forms" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
                                        "Name" : "Employee Information",
                                        "Description" : "",
                                        "IsActive" : true
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
                                        "Name" : "test form",
                                        "Description" : "",
                                        "IsActive" : true
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5afc23f3382646009c5210ab"),
                                        "Name" : "Android test",
                                        "Description" : "",
                                        "IsActive" : true
                                }
                        ],
                        "IsActive" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ffc11c70c513bc9dbfb1"),
                        "Name" : "apadei ief",
                        "Description" : "ttasdadet",
                        "Forms" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b03ff291c70c513bc9dbfa8"),
                                        "Name" : "Employee Information",
                                        "Description" : "",
                                        "IsActive" : true
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b16238f30491d1c643f7f28"),
                                        "Name" : "test form",
                                        "Description" : "",
                                        "IsActive" : true
                                }
                        ],
                        "IsActive" : true
                }
        ],
        "IsDeleted" : false
}
```

Comment: If i want to filter the Projects with IsActive = true and IsDeleted = false, than what should i do in this aggregate.